# Query to Combine Two Results Depends On Condition

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Select SUM(Breakfast) FROM `expense` WHERE MONTHNAME(Date)='February'

Select (BreakFast+lunch+dinner) as Total FROM `expense` WHERE Date='2016-01-01'
```

Combined results Depends on the Condition.

1. `SUM(Breakfast)` should be select if it is month of February.

If not means

2. `(BreakFast+lunch+dinner) as Total` Must come on particular Date.

I Tried the Union But I did not get desired result

```
Table expense
--------------
Date     Breakfast  Lunch  Dinner
2016-02-02 20 20 30 
2016-02-03 30 30 20
2016-01-02 40 30 20                     90(If It is a month Of  Not a Feb)         




           50(If It is a month Of Feb)
           --------------------------
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?  You have tagged them both.

Comment: Not sure what the question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Union ALL:

```
Select SUM(Breakfast) as Total FROM `expense` WHERE month(Date)=2
union all
Select Sum(BreakFast)+sum(lunch)+sum(dinner) as Total FROM `expense` WHERE month(Date)<>2
```

Using Case (The fastest option):

```
 SELECT CASE 
 WHEN MONTH(DATE)=2 THEN SUM(Breakfast)  
 WHEN MONTH(DATE)<>2 THEN SUM(BreakFast)+SUM(lunch)+SUM(dinner) 
 ELSE 0 END
 AS Total FROM `expense`
```

Comment: It's very likely a `case` expression would be faster than the union.

Comment: @shawnt00 it's very likely a small table so both options are the same.

Comment: It's a contrived homework problem. One legitimate consideration though is the risk of double-counting when the two sets of rows are not disjoint.

Comment: @shawnt00: you mean the month when it's February and it's not February in the same time?

Comment: Your answer is appropriate for the exercise the teacher gave; I'm not making an issue of that. You know what I'm taking about though when the conditions become more complicated or people are just careless.

Comment: Sorry if I came across as pedantic. No need to attribute me in the answer and I will upvote. My original comment was directed at OP and that was before I realized it was definitely a homework problem.